# Examples of homothetic Killing vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

A vector field $X$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is called homothetic Killing if $\mathcal{L}_X g=\lambda g$, where $\lambda$ is a constant.

If $\lambda=0$ then $X$ is simply called a Killing vector field.

If $(M,g)$ is a complete Riemannian manifold and there exist (non-zero) $X$ such that $\lambda \neq 0$ then $M$ is necessarily $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard Euclidean metric. One such vector field $X$ is the Euler vector field $r \partial_r$, where $r$ is the radial coordinate on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is aside from the Euler vector field, are there any other homothetic vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$?  Of course we can just add Killing vector fields to $r\partial_r$ but aside from doing that, is there any other genuine homothetic vector field?

Comment: Conjugate by a translation — so consider the Euler vector field based at an arbitrary point, rather than at the origin.

Comment: And that should be all of them? @TedShifrin

Comment: I doubt it. Surely you can compose with arbitrary isometries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any two (not necessarily proper) (smooth) global homothetic vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a manifold $M$ it is easy to check that some linear combination of them is a global Killing vector field on $M$.

Thus if $X$ is a *proper* global homothetic vector field on $M$, any other global homothetic vector field on $M$ is a linear combination of $X$ and a global Killing vector field on $M$.

So the dimension of the Lie algebra of global homothetic vector fields either equals, or is one greater than, the dimension of the Lie algebra of global Killing vector fields. This gives the required answer in the sense that there is essentially only one independent proper homothetic vector field on $M$ (up to scaling and additive Killing vector fields).